# BufWriterAsync nor BufWriter in Deno/TypeScript doesnt write anything to console

Tags: typescript, buffer, stdout, deno

The problem is that, when trying to run BUFFER.writeSync in any type of loop it simply writes nothing to the buffer for some reason, outside for loop it writes normally.

Expected list text in console got nothing.
Code:

```
import { BufWriterSync } from "https://deno.land/std@0.182.0/io/buf_writer.ts";

const BUFFER = BufWriterSync.create(Deno.stdout);
const TEXT_ENCODER = new TextEncoder();

function main() {
  const range = new Uint32Array().fill(1, 0, 1000);
  //BUFFER.reset(Deno.stdout);
  range.forEach(number => {
    BUFFER.writeSync(TEXT_ENCODER.encode(number.toString()))
    if (!isEven(number)) {
      BUFFER.writeSync(TEXT_ENCODER.encode(`${number} is odd`));
    } else {
      BUFFER.writeSync(TEXT_ENCODER.encode(`${number} is even`));
    }
  })
  console.log(BUFFER.buffered());
}

Deno.bench("benchmark", function () {
  main();
});

function isEven(num: number): boolean {
  return num % 2 == 0;
}

if (import.meta.main) {
  main();
}
```

Comment: FWIW: [`Deno.stdout`](https://deno.land/api@v1.32.3?s=Deno.stdout) is already a [`Writer`](https://deno.land/api@v1.32.3?s=Deno.Writer) and [`WriterSync`](https://deno.land/api@v1.32.3?s=Deno.WriterSync), so you might find it simpler to use an abstraction like this: [example](https://tsplay.dev/mbvabm)

Comment: the idea of the code is to buffer the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't seeing your expected writes to the console because your `range` array is empty.

I suggest passing in a `length` value (e.g. `2000`) to your `new Uint32Array()` constructor call:

```
  const range = new Uint32Array(2000).fill(1, 0, 1000);
```

Example output:

```
11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd11 is odd00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 is even00 i2616
```